# Support Of Distribution Of Sum Of Two Discrete Random Variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Bbb R,B(\Bbb R),P_X)$ and $(\Bbb R,B(\Bbb R),P_Y)$ are two discrete probability distribution of some random variable $X$ and $Y$ respectively  with countable support $S=\{s_1,s_2...\}$  and  $Q=\{q_1,q_2...\}$  respectively. and let $Z=X+Y$.
I think $P_Z$ is discrete with support $$ S+Q=\{s+q : s\in S , q\in Q\}$$
**Proof:**

Since $S+Q$ is countable let $$ S+Q= \{a_1,a_2,....\}$$
for each $i$ Define $A_i=\{(s,q)\in S\times Q : s+q=a_i \}$ then $$ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i=S\times Q$$Now $$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P \left(\{X+Y=a_i\}\right) &\geq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left\{\sum_{(s,q)\in A_i } P \left(X=s,Y=q\right) \right\} \tag{1}\\~\\
&=\sum_{(s,q)\in S\times Q} P \left(X=s,Y=q\right) \tag{2}\\~\\
&=\sum_{s\in S} \sum_{q\in Q} P \left(X=s,Y=q\right) \\~\\
&=\sum_{s \in S} P(X=s)\\~\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$
So $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P \left(\{X+Y=a_i\}\right) =1$$

> Is my above claim and proof correct ?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? Also, the triples $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}), P)$ are probability *spaces*, not distributions.

Comment: @JoseAvilez  No $X$ and $Y$ are not independent .

Comment: Then you need more information to compute the support of $X+Y$. (e.g. consider the case for $X=Y$ supported on $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @JoseAvilez You mean support of $X+Y$ can be larger ?

Comment: $P(X+Y\in S+Q)\geq P(X\in S, Y\in Q)=1$ where we need independence here?

Comment: Suppose you flip $10$ coins. Let $X$ be the number of heads, and $Y$ be the number of tails. 

The support of $X$ and $Y$ are both equal to $\{0,1,\dots,10\}$. 

However, the support of $X+Y$ is just $\{10\}$, because $X+Y$ is the total number of coins. This is a counterexample to your claim, because $\{0,\dots,10\}+\{0,\dots,10\}=\{0,\dots,20\}$. That is, it is possible to have $\text{support}(X+Y)\neq (\text{support }X)+(\text{support }Y)$ in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Comment: @MikeEarnest  Can we say  support$~\subset S+Q$ always ?

Comment: @MeetPatel Yes, that is true.